# Terraform nested loop in nested list

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

I'm trying to create a dynamic method to create vms in multiple environments that will be configured by the end user.
Tried for loops with nested loops. flatten function, count, etc but haven't found a way to reach my goal.
I have terrafrom.tfvars with the follwing structure:

```
Bigip_devices = {
    main_hub = {
      region             = "eastus"
      azs                = ["1"]            #Azure availabilty zones
      vnet_name               = "vnet-main"   # Vnet name to deploy to
      bigip_instance_count = 2            # Number of instnaces to delpoy
      cluster             = "yes"         # Deploy as a cluster or stand alone device
      version             = ""            # Leave blank for default value
      sku                 = ""            # Leave blank for default value - f5-bigip-virtual-edition-25m-best-hourly
      offer               = ""            # Leave blank for default value - f5-big-ip-best
      instance_type       = ""            # Leave blank for default value - Standard_DS3_v2
      disable_password_authentication = ""     #Leave blank for default value
      tags                = ""
    }
    spoke = {
      region             = "eastus"
      azs                = ["1","2"]            #Azure availabilty zones
      vnet_name               = "vnet-spoke"   # Vnet name to deploy to
      bigip_instance_count = 4            # Number of instnaces to delpoy
      cluster             = "yes"         # Deploy as a cluster or stand alone device
      version             = ""            # Leave blank for default value
      sku                 = ""            # Leave blank for default value - f5-bigip-virtual-edition-25m-best-hourly
      offer               = ""            # Leave blank for default value - f5-big-ip-best
      instance_type       = ""            # Leave blank for default value - Standard_DS3_v2
      disable_password_authentication = ""     #Leave blank for default value
      tags                = ""
    }
  }
```

What is the correct method to iterate each key in the list( in the example the are 2 keys - main hub and spoke) and to create the amount of virtual machines corresponding to the **bigip_instance_count** setting.
In the above example, I want to create 2 environments, one with 2 devices and the second with 4 devices.
Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be really convenient if you transform the above complex JSON into a collection that has one element per resource you want to create.  To achieve this, you could use the `flatten` function.

```
locals {
  # A list of objects with one object per instance.
  flattened_values = flatten([
    for ip_key, ip in var.Bigip_devices : [
      for index in range(ip.bigip_instance_count) : {
        region  = ip.region
        azs            = ip.azs
        ip_index      = index
        ip_key        = ip_key
        cluster         = ip.cluster
        version        = ip.version
        sku   = ip.sku
        offer = ip.offer
        instance_type = ip.instance_type
        disable_password_authentication = ip.disable_password_authentication
        tags = ip.tags
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

With the above `flattened` function, you get below list of collection of resources, you would like to create.

```
flattened_value_output = [
  {
    "azs" = [
      "1",
    ]
    "cluster" = "yes"
    "disable_password_authentication" = ""
    "instance_type" = ""
    "ip_index" = 0
    "ip_key" = "main_hub"
    "offer" = ""
    "region" = "eastus"
    "sku" = ""
    "tags" = ""
    "version" = ""
  },
  {
    "azs" = [
      "1",
    ]
    "cluster" = "yes"
    "disable_password_authentication" = ""
    "instance_type" = ""
    "ip_index" = 1
    "ip_key" = "main_hub"
    "offer" = ""
    "region" = "eastus"
    "sku" = ""
    "tags" = ""
    "version" = ""
  },
  {
    "azs" = [
      "1",
      "2",
    ]
    "cluster" = "yes"
    "disable_password_authentication" = ""
    "instance_type" = ""
    "ip_index" = 0
    "ip_key" = "spoke"
    "offer" = ""
    "region" = "eastus"
    "sku" = ""
    "tags" = ""
    "version" = ""
  },
  {
    "azs" = [
      "1",
      "2",
    ]
    "cluster" = "yes"
    "disable_password_authentication" = ""
    "instance_type" = ""
    "ip_index" = 1
    "ip_key" = "spoke"
    "offer" = ""
    "region" = "eastus"
    "sku" = ""
    "tags" = ""
    "version" = ""
  },
  {
    "azs" = [
      "1",
      "2",
    ]
    "cluster" = "yes"
    "disable_password_authentication" = ""
    "instance_type" = ""
    "ip_index" = 2
    "ip_key" = "spoke"
    "offer" = ""
    "region" = "eastus"
    "sku" = ""
    "tags" = ""
    "version" = ""
  },
  {
    "azs" = [
      "1",
      "2",
    ]
    "cluster" = "yes"
    "disable_password_authentication" = ""
    "instance_type" = ""
    "ip_index" = 3
    "ip_key" = "spoke"
    "offer" = ""
    "region" = "eastus"
    "sku" = ""
    "tags" = ""
    "version" = ""
  },
]
```

From the above collection, you could iterate & create resources with unique keys like below::

```
resource "some_resource" "example" {
  for_each = {
    # Generate a unique string identifier for each instance
    for ip in local.flattened_value_output : format("%s-%02d", ip.ip_key, ip.ip_index + 1) => ip
  }
}
```

This way, the creation or updating of resources is guaranteed as each resource uses a unique key.

For more details, refer [this discussion](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/create-resources-iterating-through-the-values-of-a-map-rather-key/6003/2) I had with Hashicorp personnel.

Comment: Awesome solution! Thanks, works like a charm. The example and the explanation is great as well.