# How to create multiple target groups for multiple instances in aws using terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have 3 services called valid,jsc,test and each having 3 instances in 3 zones.Now i have to create a target group for each service and attach instances to the same.Now i don't know how to combine the ports 80,443 with service names to create a target group

```
variable "service-names" {
  type = list
  default = ["valid","jsc","test"]
  
}

variable "net-lb-ports" {
  type    = map(number)
  default = {
  TCP = 80
  TCP = 443
  }
}
```

Now i have to combine this service-names variable (list) and net-lb-ports(map) for creating target group

I was able to do below but for only 1 port and that also by hartcoded the values

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "ecom-nlb-tgp" {
   for_each = toset(var.service-names)
   name = "${each.value}-nlbtgp"
   port = 80
   protocol = "TCP"
   vpc_id = aws_vpc.ecom-vpc.id
   target_type = "instance"
   deregistration_delay    = 90
   health_check {
     interval            = 30
     port                = 80
    protocol            = "TCP"
     healthy_threshold   = 3
     unhealthy_threshold = 3
   }
   tags = {
     "Name" = "${each.value}-nlb-tgp"
   }
```

So total i need 6 target groups which 3 (service-names) * 2 ports(80,443)

Please guide me

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64324121/terraform-nested-loop-in-nested-list

Comment: All  3 services  have exactly same ports?

Comment: @Marcin yes all 3 service are same ports

Comment: If all 3 services have same ports, why not just hard code them, or assign directly from a variable? There is no need for any loops if the ports are always same.

Comment: @marcin in future it may change so thats why I don't want to hardcode them

Answer (score 0):

I changed the variable as like below and was able to create the target groups

```
   variable net-lb-ports {
      type = map
      default = { 
    port1 = {
    port = 80
    protocol = "TCP"
    }
    port2 = {
    port = 443
    protocol = "TCP"
    }
      }
    }

    locals {
      merged_lbport_svc = flatten([
        for s in var.service-names :  [
          for v in var.net-lb-ports : {
            service = s
            port = v.port
            protocol = v.protocol
          }
        ]
      ])
    }

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "ecom-nlb-tgp" {
  for_each = {for idx,svc in local.merged_lbport_svc : "${svc.service}-${svc.port}-${svc.protocol}" => svc}
  #for_each = {for idx,svc in local.merged_lbport_svc : idx => svc}
  name = "ecom-${each.value.service}-${each.value.port}-${each.value.protocol}-nlbtgp"
  port = each.value.port
  protocol = each.value.protocol
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.ecom-vpc.id
  target_type = "instance"
  deregistration_delay    = 90
  health_check {
    interval            = 30
    port                = each.value.port
    protocol            = each.value.protocol
    healthy_threshold   = 3
    unhealthy_threshold   = 3
    }
   tags = {
     "Name" = "ecom-${each.value.service}-${each.value.port}-${each.value.protocol}-nlbtgp"
   } 
 }
```