# Openstack: Terraform multiple Instances with additional Disks - for_each list(object)

Tags: terraform, openstack

I’m currently trying to create several instances under Openstack with Terraform. Afterwards I want to attach more of them. But I’m not getting anywhere with the last point.
Does anyone have an idea how I can solve it?

```
variable "instances" {
  description = "The Instances to be deployed"
  type = map(object({
    name             = string
    image            = string
    flavor           = string
    volume_size      = number
    security_groups  = list(string)
    network          = string
    keypair_name     = string
    floating_ip_pool = string
    tags             = list(string)
    additional_disks = list(object({
      disk        = string
      volume_size = number
    }))
  }))
}

instances = {
  "Websrv01" = {
    name             = "websrv01"
    image            = "Ubuntu 22.04"
    flavor           = "SCS-2V-4-20s"
    volume_size      = 20
    security_groups  = ["default"]
    network          = "test-intern"
    keypair_name     = "ssh-pub"
    floating_ip_pool = "public"
    tags             = ["general", "webserver"]
    additional_disks = []
  },
  "dbsrv01" = {
    name             = "dbsrv01"
    image            = "Ubuntu 22.04"
    flavor           = "SCS-2V-4-20s"
    volume_size      = 20
    security_groups  = ["default"]
    network          = "test-intern"
    keypair_name     = "ssh-pub"
    floating_ip_pool = "public"
    tags             = ["general", "dbserver"]
    additional_disks = [
      { disk = "db_data", volume_size = 30 },
      { disk = "db_log", volume_size = 10 }
    ]
  }
}

resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "instances" {
  for_each = var.instances

  name            = each.value.name
  flavor_id       = data.openstack_compute_flavor_v2.flavor[each.key].id
  key_pair        = each.value.keypair_name
  security_groups = each.value.security_groups

  ## Boot Disk
  block_device {
    uuid                  = data.openstack_images_image_v2.image[each.key].id
    source_type           = "image"
    volume_size           = each.value.volume_size
    boot_index            = 0
    destination_type      = "volume"
    delete_on_termination = true
  }
 
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true

  network {
    name = each.value.network
  }

  tags = each.value.tags
}

## Get floating IP if needed
resource "openstack_networking_floatingip_v2" "floating_ip" {
  for_each = { for k, v in var.instances : k => v if v.floating_ip_pool != "" }

  pool = each.value.floating_ip_pool
}

## Associate floating ip to Instances
resource "openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2" "associate" {
  for_each = openstack_networking_floatingip_v2.floating_ip

  instance_id = openstack_compute_instance_v2.instances[each.key].id
  floating_ip = each.value.address
}

## Additional Disks
resource "openstack_blockstorage_volume_v3" "additional_disks" {
  for_each = {
    for instance, disks in var.instances : instance => disks.additional_disks
    if length(disks.additional_disks) > 0
  }

  name                 = "${each.key}-${each.value[0].disk}"
  size                 = each.value[0].volume_size
  enable_online_resize = true
}

## Attach additional disks to instances
resource "openstack_compute_volume_attach_v2" "attach_additional_disks" {
  for_each = {
    for instance, disks in var.instances : instance => disks.additional_disks
    if length(disks.additional_disks) > 0
  }

  instance_id = openstack_compute_instance_v2.instances[each.key].id
  volume_id   = openstack_blockstorage_volume_v3.additional_disks[each.key].id
}
```

Only the first hard disk is taken into account here.
Ich i try to loop truth the list, with [*] it fails.

regards
Eddi

with single addition Disk it works:

```
resource "openstack_blockstorage_volume_v3" "additional_disks" {
  for_each = {
    for instance, disks in var.instances : instance => disks.additional_disks
    if length(disks.additional_disks) > 0
  }

  name                 = "${each.key}-${each.value[0].disk}"
  size                 = each.value[0].volume_size
  enable_online_resize = true
}

resource "openstack_compute_volume_attach_v2" "attach_additional_disks" {
  for_each = {
    for instance, disks in var.instances : instance => disks.additional_disks
    if length(disks.additional_disks) > 0
  }

  instance_id = openstack_compute_instance_v2.instances[each.key].id
  volume_id   = openstack_blockstorage_volume_v3.additional_disks[each.key].id
}
```

Comment: What's the error message? Which one is failing? `volume` creation or `attach`?

Comment: I see you must have problems with `attach`. You cannot use the same `var.instances` logic for both `additional_disks` & `attach`. You have to multiply `additional_disks` & `var.instances`, index them & store in some `locals` var. This way you have the complete number of disks and which disk needs to be mapped where & then it should work fine.

Comment: it works only with one Disk.
>  name                 = "${each.key}-${each.value[0].disk}"
>  size                   = each.value[0].volume_size

If i remove the [0], i got a error, because there is more then one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had already tried to solve it with ChatGPT. And he was already on the right track. But had not suggested a solution with locals. Had tried it in the for_each loop using flatten.
I am not yet familiar with flatten and locals.
Now I have changed the solution a bit, in a simpler notation, after ChatGPT had suggested to convert to a map(object).

This is what my solution looks like now:

```
variable "instances" {
  description = "The Instances to be deployed"
  type = map(object({
    name             = string
    image            = string
    flavor           = string
    volume_size      = number
    security_groups  = list(string)
    network          = string
    keypair_name     = string
    floating_ip_pool = string
    tags             = list(string)
    additional_disks = map(object({
      volume_size = number
    }))
  }))
}

instances = {
  "Websrv01" = {
    name             = "websrv01"
    image            = "Ubuntu 22.04"
    flavor           = "SCS-2V-4-20s"
    volume_size      = 20
    security_groups  = ["default"]
    network          = "test-intern"
    keypair_name     = "ssh_general"
    floating_ip_pool = "public"
    tags             = ["general", "webserver"]
    additional_disks = {}
  },
  "Websrv02" = {
    name             = "websrv02"
    image            = "Ubuntu 22.04"
    flavor           = "SCS-2V-4-20s"
    volume_size      = 20
    security_groups  = ["default"]
    network          = "test-intern"
    keypair_name     = "ssh_general"
    floating_ip_pool = "public"
    tags             = ["general", "webserver"]
    additional_disks = {}
  },
  "dbsrv01" = {
    name             = "dbsrv01"
    image            = "Ubuntu 22.04"
    flavor           = "SCS-2V-4-20s"
    volume_size      = 20
    security_groups  = ["default"]
    network          = "test-intern"
    keypair_name     = "ssh_general"
    floating_ip_pool = "public"
    tags             = ["general", "dbserver"]
    additional_disks = {
      db_data = { volume_size = 30 },
      db_log  = { volume_size = 10 }
    }
  }
}

## create a flatten structure vom var.instances
locals {
  additional_disks = flatten([
    for instance_key, instance in var.instances : [
      for disk_name, disk in instance.additional_disks : {
        instance_key = instance_key
        disk_name    = disk_name
        disk_values  = disk
      }
    ]
  ])
}

## Create Additional Disks for Instances  
resource "openstack_blockstorage_volume_v3" "additional_disks" {
  for_each = {
    for disk in local.additional_disks : "${disk.instance_key}-${disk.disk_name}" => disk
  }

  name                 = each.key
  size                 = each.value.disk_values.volume_size
  enable_online_resize = true
}

## Attach additional disks to instances
resource "openstack_compute_volume_attach_v2" "attach_additional_disks" {
  for_each = {
    for disk in local.additional_disks : "${disk.instance_key}-${disk.disk_name}" => disk
  }

  instance_id = openstack_compute_instance_v2.instances[each.value.instance_key].id
  volume_id   = openstack_blockstorage_volume_v3.additional_disks[each.key].id
}
```

I will also implement the tip with enable_online_resize.

Another question. I would like to use the code in several environments, so it will certainly make sense to create a module from it?
Then I'll give it a try now.

And finally, I would like to generate a dynamic inventory in INI format for Ansible and group it with the tags. Are there any easy ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This question is more or less similar to the one asked & answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64324121/terraform-nested-loop-in-nested-list/64324491#64324491). Nevertheless, I want to make it easy for you.

If you want iterate over multiple objects in a json object & have appropriate correlation with parent objects, it is recommended to use `flatten` function & extract relevant fields of your interest for further iteration.

Below `locals` var does exactly the same ::

```
locals {
  additional_disks = flatten([
    for instance_key, instance in var.instances : [
      for index in range(length(instance.additional_disks)) : {
        local_disk_index = index % length(instance.additional_disks)
        instance_key     = instance_key
        disk_key         = format("%s-%s", instance_key, instance.additional_disks[index % length(instance.additional_disks)].disk)
        disk_values      = instance.additional_disks[index % length(instance.additional_disks)]
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

We construct a list of objects with `instance_key` for `lookup` of instances & then associated `disk` keys & values to it.

The above `local.additional_disks` could be used like below to provision the resources.

```
## Additional Disks    
resource "openstack_blockstorage_volume_v3" "additional_disks" {
  for_each = {
    for disk in local.additional_disks: disk.disk_key => disk
  }     
      
  name                 = each.value.disk_values.disk
  size                 = each.value.disk_values.volume_size
  enable_online_resize = true
}

## Attach additional disks to instances
resource "openstack_compute_volume_attach_v2" "attach_additional_disks" {   
        
  for_each = {
    for disk in local.additional_disks: disk.disk_key => disk
  } 
  
  instance_id = openstack_compute_instance_v2.instances[each.value.instance_key].id
  volume_id   = openstack_blockstorage_volume_v3.additional_disks[each.key].id
}
```

And the `terraform plan` gives below output ::

```
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

...blah-blah..
# openstack_blockstorage_volume_v3.additional_disks["dbsrv01-db_data"] will be created
  + resource "openstack_blockstorage_volume_v3" "additional_disks" {
      + attachment           = (known after apply)
      + availability_zone    = (known after apply)
      + enable_online_resize = true
      + id                   = (known after apply)
      + metadata             = (known after apply)
      + name                 = "db_data"
      + region               = (known after apply)
      + size                 = 30
      + volume_type          = (known after apply)
    }

  # openstack_blockstorage_volume_v3.additional_disks["dbsrv01-db_log"] will be created
  + resource "openstack_blockstorage_volume_v3" "additional_disks" {
      + attachment           = (known after apply)
      + availability_zone    = (known after apply)
      + enable_online_resize = true
      + id                   = (known after apply)
      + metadata             = (known after apply)
      + name                 = "db_log"
      + region               = (known after apply)
      + size                 = 10
      + volume_type          = (known after apply)
    }
...blah-blah..
 # openstack_compute_volume_attach_v2.attach_additional_disks["dbsrv01-db_data"] will be created
  + resource "openstack_compute_volume_attach_v2" "attach_additional_disks" {
      + device      = (known after apply)
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + instance_id = (known after apply)
      + region      = (known after apply)
      + volume_id   = (known after apply)
    }

  # openstack_compute_volume_attach_v2.attach_additional_disks["dbsrv01-db_log"] will be created
  + resource "openstack_compute_volume_attach_v2" "attach_additional_disks" {
      + device      = (known after apply)
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + instance_id = (known after apply)
      + region      = (known after apply)
      + volume_id   = (known after apply)
    }
```

Another unasked advice, I see you hardcode `enable_online_resize` directly on the resource. This isn't a good idea, pull it from the `additional_disks` attribute by hardcoding it to `true`.

Comment: You are my Hero, thanks for your Support!!!
That works's for me!